# Is strong convergence of measures equivalent to convergence in measure of the Radon Nikodym derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a measure space, and suppose $\mu_i$ are probability measures on $X$ that are absolutely continuous with respect to another probability measure $\mu$. Is strong convergence of $\mu_i$ to $\mu$ equivalent to convergence in measure (wrt $\mu$) of the Radon nikodym derivatives $\frac{d\mu_i}{d\mu}$ to $1$?

Comment: From wiki: "For example, as a consequence of the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma, the sequence μ_n of measures on the interval [−1, 1] given by μ_n(dx) = (1+ sin(nx))dx converges strongly to Lebesgue measure."

Comment: @ Fedor Petrov - it depends on what the OP meant by strong convergence of measures. I was surprised to learn that wiki (apparently this is the article you quote) introduces a rather artificial notion of "strong convergence" of measures (I have never come across it in real life) and distinguishes it from the convergence in total variation ($\equiv$ convergence in the strong topology on the space of measures). This is not the first time I come across highly dubious claims in wiki.

Comment: I did indeed mean convergence in the sense stated by wiki..

Comment: If it’s meant in the other sense is it true?

Comment: It seems like it is indeed true, if I didn’t make any mistakes.

Comment: Wikipedia's "strong convergence" is called "setwise convergence" in Bogachev's measure theory.  It'd be helpful to have the definition in your question.

Comment: Note, however, that under your assumptions the Radon-Nikodym derivatives in fact converge to 1 in $L^1(\mu)$.  If I'm not mistaken, that is equivalent to convergence in total variation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_n:=\{x\colon f_n(x)\le1\}$ and $B_n:=\{x\colon f_n(x)>1\}$, where $f_n:=\frac{d\mu_n}{d\mu}$. Then the total variation of $\mu_n-\mu$ is 
$$\|\mu_n-\mu\|=\int_{B_n}(f_n-1)d\mu+\int_{A_n}(1-f_n)d\mu=2\int_{A_n}(1-f_n)d\mu\to0$$
by dominated convergence if $f_n\to1$ in measure wrt $\mu$; the latter displayed equality is the key, even though simple, observation here.

Vice versa,
$$\|\mu_n-\mu\|=\int_X|f_n-1|d\mu.$$
So, as noted by Nate Eldredge, $\|\mu_n-\mu\|\to0$ means that $f_n\to1$ in $L^1(\mu)$, which implies, by Markov's inequality 
$$\mu\{x\colon|f_n(x)-1|>\epsilon\}\le\frac1\epsilon\,\int_X|f_n-1|d\mu$$
for all $\epsilon>0$, that $f_n\to1$ in measure wrt $\mu$.

Thus, $\mu_n\to\mu$ in total variation iff $\frac{d\mu_n}{d\mu}\to1$ in measure wrt $\mu$.